# TypeError: display.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

**react code**

*I know this is a small problem but I am learning in react*

> when I display data by using console.log it display properly
> but I trying display on screen I facing this error `TypeError: display.map is not a function`

*I think, it's wrong here*

```
const recipeApi = async() =>{
  const ID = '96ffd3cd';
  const KEY = 'd66772eb315fdcd45e86cdb4579f1888';
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${ID}&app_key=${KEY}`);
  const jsonData = await response.json();

  setDisplay(jsonData)
  console.log(setDisplay)
}
```

---

**full code**

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
   const [display, setDisplay] = useState([]);

 useEffect(()=>{
   recipeApi()
 },[])  


const recipeApi = async() =>{
   const ID = '96ffd3cd';
  const KEY = 'd66772eb315fdcd45e86cdb4579f1888';
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${ID}&app_key=${KEY}`);
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  
  setDisplay(jsonData)
  console.log(setDisplay)
}
  

  return (
     <div className="App">
        <div className='recipe-item'>
        {display.map((values) =>{
           return(
              <div>
                 <div>{values}</div>
              </div>
           )
        })}
           
       </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: May I see your **jsonData**?

Comment: fyi your console.log is only showing `setDisplay` - a function. It's not showing you `jsonData`. Change it and check what the json data actually looks like as per my answer

Comment: I would suggest not to put your actual `id` and `key` in the post as anyone can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON response is not an array.

[image]

Your code should be something like below.

```
   {display && Array.isArray(display.hits) &&  display.hits.map((item) =>{
       return(
          <div>
             <div>{item.recipe.label}</div>
          </div>
       )
    })}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Your console.log is displaying `setDisplay`, the method. It's not displaying your json data.*

Your `jsonData` is not being returned as an array. Inspect the structure of your json Data closely.

When you do `setDisplay(jsonData)` ensure that what you're setting in the state is actually an array and not an object.

It's highly possible that your `jsonData` looks like an object like:

```
{
  data: [....]
}
```

or some other field name where the value is an array.

Using that field name, you'll want to do

```
setDisplay(jsonData.data);
```

(Again, where `.data` is whatever the field name is in the json object being returned by the API that is an array).

**Edit:** I looked at the API response using the key and ID in your code.

The structure looks like this:

```
{
 hits: [ {recipe: {...}}, {recipe: {...}}, {recipe: {...}}]
}
```

I'm guessing you want to display the recipes so you should do this in your fetch:

```
const recipeApi = async() =>{
  const ID = '<YOUR ID HERE';
  const KEY = '<YOUR KEY HERE>';
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${ID}&app_key=${KEY}`);
  const jsonData = await response.json();

  setDisplay(jsonData.hits) // now contains an array of objects containing recipe objects
  console.log(jsonData.hits)
}
```

Now in your App component's JSX, you can't simply put an object in JSX (it'll error out) since `values` is now an object containing 1 key, `recipe`, and a bunch of values.

Work with your data to see what you want to actually show but for now a simple thing you could do is just show each recipe's label:

```
return (
     <div className="App">
        <div className='recipe-item'>
        {display.map((recipeData) =>{
           return(
              <div>
                 <div>{recipeData.recipe.label}</div>
              </div>
           )
        })}
           
       </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `jsonData` is an object, not an array. That is why you won't be able to use `.map` on the `display` value.

Here's the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-kare-jvtsnd?file=/src/App.js:0-789) to the code.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    recipeApi();
  }, []);

  const recipeApi = async () => {
    const ID = "96ffd3cd";
    const KEY = "d66772eb315fdcd45e86cdb4579f1888";
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${ID}&app_key=${KEY}`
    );
    const jsonData = await response.json();

    console.log("json data ->", jsonData);

    setDisplay(jsonData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="recipe-item">
        <div>{display.q}</div>
        <div>{display.from}</div>
        <div>{display.to}</div>
        <div>{display.more}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is not what they're trying to do. Their code is clearly trying to display data from an array of values. They're likely trying to access the `hits` field that contain recipes.

Answer (score 0):

Map Function only Works with Arrays and when you update state from `setDisplay`, then the updated state will be an JSON object. So you must have to set an Array in State to perform a Map Function